# pythontex - How to choose the version of Python used?

Tags: python

I have two versions. How can I tell to pythontex the path to the Python3 to be used if it is possible ?

Comment: How do you do this with a non-TeX way?

Comment: Which operating system do you use, how did you install the various versions of `python` that are on your system, and what are the versions' numbers.

Comment: Typically, I use Anaconda with Python 3 and Python 2 is the standard one from my distribution. I work on all platforms : Mac O$, Windows and Lubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the `pythontex` documentation (bottom of subsection 2.2 in v0.12?); it lists a number of options that `pythontex.py` accepts, including the following one, which allows you to specify the interpreter that `pythontex` should use:

> `--interpreter`
>
> This allows the interpreter for a given language to be specified. The argument should be in the form
>
> ```
> --interpreter "<interpreter>:<command>, <interp>:<cmd>, ..."
> ```
>
> where `<interpreter>` is `python`, `ruby`, etc., and `<command>` is the command for invoking the desired interpreter. The argument to `--interpreter` may also be in the form of a Python dictionary. The argument need not be enclosed in quotation marks if it contains no spaces.
>
> For example, by default Python code is executed with whatever interpreter the `python` command invokes. But Python 3 could be specified using `--interpreter python:python3` (many Linux distributions) or `--interpreter "python:py -3"` (Windows, with Python 3.3 installed so that the py wrapper is available).

Comment: Thanks. I really think that the documentation should put this in a dedicated section.

Comment: GPoore, the author of `pythontex`, is active on TeX.SX. I'm sure he'll see your question and he might take your suggestion onboard for a future release.

Comment: That was just a suggestion. ;-)

Comment: @projetmbc I've added a note about `--interpreter` to the quickstart for the next release.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

In the document [The PythonTex package](https://repo.skni.umcs.pl/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/pythontex.pdf) there is an explanation:

> --interpreter python:python3

So I changed my sublime-build to:

> "shell_cmd": "pdflatex $file_name && pythontex $file_name --interpreter python:python3 && pdflatex $file_name"

and it worked just fine.
I don't know, however, how to make `\usepackage{python}` use python3... It worked and suddenly started using python2...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the OP wanted to use `pythontex`, but he had Python 2 and Python 3 installed.  Under these circumstances, if you want to use Python 3 in your *tex* files, the `--interpreter` flag is supposed to work.

Alas, I could not get that `--interpreter` to work, and I nearly gave up.

Taking a closer look at the `pythontex.py` module, I noticed that it calls another module named `pythontex3.py` when it detects Python 3 is the default on your system.

So: you can *tell your pythontex installation to use Python 3* by invoking  `pythontex3.py` instead of `pythontex.py` when building your *tex* file.

On my system I found this module at:

`/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex3.py`

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, could you explain, how your answer solves OP's problem?

Comment: @Raaja I edited the answer a little - I hope it helps.